# Why does the wavelength of a particle go down with higher velocity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, velocity, wave-particle-duality, wavelength, dispersion

In mechanical waves, the wavelength increases with a higher velocity.
λ = v / f.
And the wavelength in particles lower with a higher velocity.
λ = h / mv.

Comment: This is a [de Broglie relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is deceptive:

$λ = v / f$  for waves  that transfer energy with a fixed velocity v in a medium. This is a constant for the medium for all waves (acoustic, even light which is in vacuum with a constant  c velocity)

> [Suggested by De Broglie in about 1923](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/debrog.html#c1), the path to the wavelength expression for a particle is by analogy to the momentum of a photon.

The [appropriate  formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html) for particles in analogy with the photon is

[image: particlewave]

the de Broglie hypothesis which can be derived from the [postulates of quantum mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) . The velocity represented by the momentum , $p$, is variable dependent on the condition of the particle.  The wave nature of the particle  is *a probability wave,* not a mass or energy wave.

A single particle does not register as a wave, it is always a point in (x,y,z,t). An accumulation of particles with the same boundary conditions will show wave behavior in the probability distribution. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62343/can-an-electron-interact-with-itself-to-create-interference/414697#414697) to see how one measures a probability distribution for a particle.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the frequency the smaller the wavelength. The higher velocity equates to higher acceleration creating higher energy (higher frequency)photons. Smaller wavelength means higher energy.

Comment: What do you mean " The higher velocity equates to higher acceleration creating higher energy (higher frequency)photons."?

Comment: velocity of what?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei velocity of a particle

Comment: Do you mean a particle that emits a photon? Do you mean that an electron accelerating, the higher acceleration, the higher frequency photon it will emit?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei yes

Comment: can you please give me a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

The de Broglie wavelength is the central wavelength of a superposition of waves forming a wave packet. The velocity in that equation is the envelope velocity of all of the combined waves (the group velocity), and differs from the individual wave velocities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "because": the dispersion relations dictate it. I'll illustrate @anna's answer in elementary mathematese, contrasting water gravity waves, in the deep ocean, to a QM particle in Schroedinger's equation.

The dispersion relation is the functional dependence of the angular frequency on the wavenumber, $\omega(k)$. The group velocity of a wavepacket is 
$$v=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k }. $$

The deep water wave dispersion relation is 
$$
\omega=\sqrt{g k},
$$ 
easily derived in books, but also from dimensional analysis, having been reassured, from generic thinking (if you trust yourself) that the *only* relevant constant involved is the acceleration of gravity *g, and nothing else*. Given that, deep water waves necessarily travel with
$$
v=\frac{\omega}{2k}\propto \sqrt{\lambda} \propto 1/\sqrt{\omega},
$$
familiar from handicapping sailboats, or from the fact short frequency waves from a boat in a lake reach you *last* as you are sitting on the shore! [Your expression is peculiar]. (This dispersion relation is also the origin of the [universal Kelvin wake angle of all swimming/sailing objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake), independent of velocity!)

Linear dispersion relations ($\omega  = a k$), for constant *a*, of course, give you *constant* speeds $v=a$--possibly that's your first equation, a possible misconception anna identified.

The dispersion relation of QM de Broglie waves from Schroedinger's equation
is radically different, 
$$
\omega=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}, 
$$ 
again dimensionally inevitable, once an Austrian gentleman reassures you these are the only constants involved. [Let's not really go there.]

The resulting speed is then 
$$
v=\hbar k/m=\frac{h}{m} \frac {1}{\lambda} ~ . 
$$ 
This is the mother of all resolution experiments, so increasing the speed and thus energy of your probing projectiles involves shorter wavelengths proving shorter distances.